# Changing Toggle Foreground Color Using IUP C/C++

Tags: c++, windows, colors, iup

Using IUP version 3.16, I am unable to change the foreground text color of a toggle.

```
Ihandle *MainHbox = IupHbox
(

  CheckBox = IupToggle("Checkbox Label", NULL),
  NULL

);

IupSetAttribute(CheckBox, "FGCOLOR", "0 255 0"); // Checkbox Label Green
```

No errors are returned, but the text color remains black.

https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/elem/iuptoggle.html

https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/en/attrib/iup_fgcolor.html

Answer (score 1):

Notice in the IupToggle documentation that in Windows using Visual Styles, i.e. when using the manifest to enable the modern interface in win32 controls, the fgcolor is ignored. This is a native system behaviour.

One alternative is to use a toggle with title="", and compose a hbox with a label.

Comment: I did notice that, and I have tried disabling Visual Styles, but fgcolor was still ignored. I may have to use labels though they have gaps, and won't be placed beside the toggle in an IupVbox.